# CMake: "dereference" INCLUDE commands to create a single CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake, cmake-language

I'd like to export/install an example project that shows how to use my CMake module (basically a C library). I'd like to distribute a `CMakeLists.txt` with the example that builds a hello-world-like executable that links with my library. The in-source version of the example's `CMakeLists.txt` `INCLUDE`s some cmake fragments that are also used elsewhere.

I'd like to replace these `INCLUDE` commands with the contents of the files (recursively) so that eventually a single `CMakeLists.txt` remains that can be distributed, similarly to what [latexepand](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexpand) does for LaTeX documents.
Is there any built-in functionality that can help with that? Searching for "cmake" and "include" is not exactly very fruitful... :)

Comment: "Is there any built-in functionality that can help with that?" - I know no such functionality, and I don't expect it to be existed. While CMake language is quite simple, it is still a sequential language. Without executing actual code one won't be able to deduce which include files are used and where to search them. If you know the way how do you use `include` directives, you could write a regex-based program to replace them. I find it simpler to distribute your example project with the scripts needed for it.